# Why these two sets are equal?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why these two sets are equal? $$\{\lambda^2 \in \mathbb{C} : Re(\lambda)\leq\omega\}=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : Re(\lambda)\leq\omega^2-\frac{Im(\lambda)^2}{4\omega^2}\}$$ where $Re(\lambda)$ (resp. $Im(\lambda)$) denote the real part (resp. the the imaginary part) of the complex number $\lambda$, and $\omega>0$.

I simplified the right hand side set in the form $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : (\omega^2-\frac{Re(\lambda)-|\lambda|}{2})(\omega^2-\frac{Re(\lambda)+|\lambda|}{2})\geq 0\}$.

Comment: I would first rewrite the left set, as either $\{\mu\in\mathbb C\mid\text{Re}(\sqrt\mu)\leq\omega\text{ and }\text{Re}(-\sqrt\mu)\leq\omega\}$ or $\{\mu\in\mathbb C\mid\text{Re}(\sqrt\mu)\leq\omega\text{ or }\text{Re}(-\sqrt\mu)\leq\omega\}$ (I haven't decided which is correct).

Comment: I found the mistake in this question. You can look at my edited part of the answer. If you print the set of parabolas, it'll be obvious that the corrected equation is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equal. For example, let $\omega=1$. Choose $\lambda=-10$. then $\lambda^2=100$, so $100\in L$ (left-hand side set). If $L=R$ then $100\in R$, that is $100\leq 1-\frac 14$, which is false.

Consider now the set $L_\omega=\{\lambda^2\in\Bbb C: \mathrm{Re}\,\lambda = \omega\}$. Then
$$L_\omega=\{(a+ib)^2\in\Bbb C: a = \omega,\ b\in\Bbb R\} = \{(\omega^2-b^2) + 2\omega bi\in\Bbb C: b\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Therefore
$$L_\omega=\{x+iy\in\Bbb C: x=\omega^2-b^2,\ y=2\omega b,\ b\in\Bbb R\}
= \left\{x+iy\in\Bbb C: x=\omega^2-\frac{y^2}{4\omega^2}\right\}=R_\omega$$
where $$R_\omega = \left\{\lambda\in\Bbb C: \mathrm{Re}\,\lambda = \omega^2-\frac{(\mathrm{Im}\,\lambda)^2}{4\omega^2}\right\}.$$

Edit:

After thinking a bit I realized how this equation should look like. There's an error with left-hand side set. There should be
$$L=\{\lambda^2 \in \mathbb{C} : 0\leq Re(\lambda)\leq\omega\}.$$ Then the set $L$ is a union of sets $L_\omega=R_\omega$, that is a set of parabolas. This union is equal to $R$.

Comment: Thanks it is clear now, add $^2$ to $(a+ib)$ in $L_\omega$.