# How to represent this set in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\omega>0$. I want to represent the set $$A_\omega=\{\lambda^2\in \mathbb{C}: Re(\lambda)\leq\omega\}$$ in the complex plane. I think it might be some parabola but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Any complex number is of the form $\lambda^{2}$ with $\Re \lambda \leq 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, my question is how to sketch it in the complex plane.

Comment: Your set is the entire complex palne.  It makes no sense to sketch it.

Comment: think of λ as x+iy. What's the real part of λ^2?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor we can write $A_\omega=\{x^2-y^2+2ixy : x\leq \omega, y\in \mathbb{R} \}$, then ?

Comment: so the real part is $x^2 - y^2$ so that last condtion should be $x^2 - y^2  <=  ω$. 
And $x^2 - y^2$ yields a hyperbola which you can look up.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor The condition is on $\,\text{Re}(\lambda) \le \omega\,$, not $\,\text{Re}(\lambda^2)\,$. The first comment is correct, for any $\,z \in \mathbb C\,$ one of the two roots of $\,\lambda^2 = z\,$ will have real part $\,\le 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I found this set in remark 5.7 page 91 of this paper : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039669901053

Comment: @HiddaWalid That's a lot of context there, and I did not (try to) follow it all. I would assume there is an assumption somewhere that $\,\lambda\,$ must be in the right half-plane, as was pointed out in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4467792/291201) to your first question.

Comment: @dxiv - you are right - I misread it